# Call specific variable in a Python function

Tags: python, function

I have a Python script called `module.py` with several functions in it, like this:

```
def foo_1():
    var = 1
    return

def foo_2():
    var = 2
    return

def foo_3():
    var = 3
    return

def foo_4():
    var = 4
    return
```

Each of the functions (foo_1, foo_2, ...) defines a unique value for the variable named `var`, and I am looking for a way to grab this value from each of the functions. Is this possible in Python? It is crucial to my project that each of the variables `var` have the same local name in their respective function.

I have already been able to grab a list of all the functions as follows:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import module

function_list = [pair[0] for pair in getmembers(module, isfunction)]
```

Which returns a list of all the functions names `[foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, foo_4]`. Now, I am looking for a way to iterate through all the functions and grab the value of `var` in each one — something like this:

```
var_value_tuples = []

for function in function_list:

     var_values.append((function, function.var))
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This is very much an anti-pattern.

Comment: Those functions don't do anything. `var` is a local variable.

Comment: It's not possible to access local variables of a function from outside the function.

Comment: You should have the function return the value with `return var`. Then you can use `var_values.append(function())`

Answer (score 1):

A different way to achieve this, that is less of an anti-pattern and does not require introspection (also does not impose any specific function signature):

```
vars = { "foo_1": 1, "foo_2": 2, "foo_3": 3, "foo_4": 4 }

def foo_1():
    var = vars["foo_1"]
    return

def foo_2():
    var = vars["foo_2"]
    return

def foo_3():
    var = vars["foo_3"]
    return

def foo_4():
    var = vars["foo_4"]
    return
```

Some things to consider:

- do these all need to be distinct functions if they have such similar implementations
- since the functions seem to have a one to one mapping, can you use a list or some other data structure to map from `vars` to functions

Ultimately this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You should add more context or outline the overall problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: The only thing I agree with in this answer (not that the suggestion is *wrong*, just dubiously applicable) is the assertion that this is an XY problem.

Comment: That's what comments are for: to figure out what the real question is.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like

- `foo_1.__code__.co_varnames` gives list of all local variables in the function
- `foo_1.__code__.co_consts` gives all the constant values,first one being the default return value i.e. `None`

```py
def foo_1():
    var = 1
    var2 = 2
    return

variables = dict(zip(foo_1.__code__.co_varnames, foo_1.__code__.co_consts[1:]))
print(variables)
```

```
{'var': 1, 'var2': 2}
```